# How can I achieve the Ken Burn Effect with greater control or in other software?

Tags: editing, final-cut-pro, keyframes

I am using the Ken Burns effect in Final Cut Pro X, however it does not allow me enough control over how it behaves.  I end up having to cut the video in to multiple clips in order to get the effect to work the way I want.

How can I achieve multiple different Ken Burns like zooms without having to cut my video in to multiple pieces to make the adjustments.  What about other software when Ken Burns isn't an effect that it has?

Answer (score 4):

What you like to accomplish is a zoom?
In that case you can just add keyframes on the position of the video within your canvas/composition.

1. Find the moment where you want to zoom.
2. Add keyframe on the scale / position
3. Add keyframe on end of the zoom
4. Set preferred value
5. Add keyframe one frame before zooming out
6. Add keyframe on that next frame.
7. Add keyframe at the end of the zoom
8. Set the value of that keyframe back to 100% (original value)

That's it!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the Ken burns effect.  Animate the transform controls, setting keyframes for scale and x/y position.  By default, the keyframes will ease in and ease out, giving you a Ken Burns like effect, but you'll be able to control it more precisely.